# Relative compact inside a subset with relative topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am a little bit confused. Assume that $Y$ is a subset of $X$, with the inherited topology from $X$. What does it mean the $K\subset Y$ is a relatively compact subset of $Y$?

One option, is that $K= C\cap Y$, where $C$ is a relatively compact subset in $X$.

Another option, is the $\overline{K}\cap Y$ is compact in $Y$.

To be specific, I am looking on the following example:

Let $X$ be a topological (locally compact Hausdorff), $\{D_n\}_{\
n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of open subsets inside $X$. For every $n$, let $T_n: D_n\to D_{-n}$ be a homeomorphism.
Consider the set $Y:=\{(T_n(x),n,x)\in X\times \mathbb{Z}\times X| x\in D_n\}$ with the inherited topology from $X\times \mathbb{Z}\times X$.

I want to say that if $K\subset Y$ is relatively compact, then $K$ is contained in a set of the form $\{(T_n(x),n,x)\in X\times \mathbb{Z}\times X| x\in D_n\cap C, \  n\in [-N,N]\}$ for some relatively compact set $C$ in $X$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to definition a subset of a topological space is [relatively compact](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subset)  if its closure (in that space) is compact.

So I suspect that $K\subseteq Y$ is a relatively compact subset of $Y$ it is closure in $Y$ is compact.

Further if $\overline K$ denotes the closure of $K$ in original space $X$ then the closure of $K$ as a subset of $Y$ equals $\overline K\cap Y$.

This results in the second option that you mention:$$K\text{ is a relatively compact subset of }Y\subseteq X\text{ iff }\overline K\cap Y\text{ is compact}$$

---

I advice you not to accept this answer, but just think it over. Maybe a real topologist will pass by to adjust.

Comment: Thank you very much, sounds good. It seems to me that in this case $\overline{K}$ is also a subset of $Y$: $\overline{K}=\overline{K\cap Y}\subseteq \overline{\overline{K}\cap Y}=\overline{K}\cap Y$, the last equality is since the intersection is compact and therefore closed in $X$. The inclusion implies that $\overline{K}\subseteq Y$. But then, the conclusion is that $K$ is a relatively compact subset of $Y$ if and only if $\overline{K}$ is contained in $Y$ and is compact(?)

Comment: "since the intersection is compact and therefore closed in $X$". Yes to this under the **extra condition** that $X$ is a Hausdorff space. In a Hausdorff space compact sets are indeed closed, and you end up with the conclusion you mention. But in general it is not true that compact sets are necessarily closed.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.